# Sum data from one table and divide it by count of rows in joined table

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I'm using postgresql. I need to sum data from one table (timeWorked from log table, summed by taskId) and then divide it by the amount of rows in the joined table (task_worker). Also join another table (task) in the process to get description but that should be easy, just keep it in mind.
What would be the most optimal query for such an operation?
So far the only solution i came up is utilising a subquery but i'm wondering if there is a better approach.

```
Log table:
taskId   timeWorked
1        60
1        90
1        120
2        180
2        210
3        90
3        180
3        90

Task table
id       description
1        making icecream
2        doing salad
3        cooking

Task_worker table
taskId   workerId
1        1
1        2
2        1
2        2
2        3
3        3
```

My expected output would be something like:

```
taskId  totalTimeWorked  description
1       135 (270 / 2)    making icecream
2       130 (390 / 3)    doing salad
3       360 (360 / 1)    cooking
```

Comment: Sum in one subquery/CTE. Count in another. Then join and divide.

Comment: @Akina ok will try that. I guess its still much better than my original idea.